# Geofences events just called with fake gps app, in real gps it is not called

Tags: android, kotlin, gps

I am creating a foreground service that creates a geofence area in user local, and when the user exit from the geofence area i create another geofence area, again in user local.

I have a low RAM Quantity so i tested on my phone android 9, and with the fake gps app, it works fine, but when i use the real gps don't. I defined the high accuracy on android phone configuration and still  doesn't work. Finally i had decided to put fire on my pc and use the emulator to control the phone location, and yet doesn't work. Not even de initial trigger is called.

So what is the difference between the fake gps and de real gps that defines if my code will work or not

```
class LocationForegroundService : LifecycleService() {

    private lateinit var geofencingClient: GeofencingClient
    private lateinit var locationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private lateinit var pendingBroadcastIntent: PendingIntent
    private var geoId = ""

    companion object {

        private var count = 0
        private var geoAlreadyInitialized = false
        private const val TRACKING_CHANNEL = "tracking_channel"
        private const val TRACKING_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1
        private lateinit var mContext: Context
        private val exitFromGeofence = MutableLiveData(false)
        var isTrackingRider: Boolean = false
            private set

        fun startService(context: Context) {
            mContext = context
            val startIntent = Intent(context, LocationForegroundService::class.java)
            ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, startIntent)
            isTrackingRider = true
        }

        fun stopService(context: Context) {
            val stopIntent = Intent(context, LocationForegroundService::class.java)
            context.stopService(stopIntent)
            isTrackingRider = false
        }

        class GeofenceReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
                val geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent)
                if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
                    return
                }
                when (geofencingEvent.geofenceTransition) {
                    GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT -> {
                        geofencingEvent.triggeringGeofences.forEach {
                            context?.showShortToast("EXIT geo ${it.requestId}")
                        }

                        exitFromGeofence.value = true
                    }
                    GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER -> {
                        geofencingEvent.triggeringGeofences.forEach {
                            context?.showShortToast("Enter geo ${it.requestId}")
                        }
                    }
                    GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL -> {
                        context?.showShortToast("dwell geo blabla")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        locationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(mContext)
        geofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(mContext)
        val intent = Intent(mContext, GeofenceReceiver::class.java)
        pendingBroadcastIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            mContext,
            0,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )
        createObservers()
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
        createNotificationChannel()

       // ... creates notification for foreground 
       updateLocation()

       return START_NOT_STICKY
    }


    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun createNewGeofence(location: Location) {
        removeActualGeofence()
        geoId = "geo_id_$count"
        val geofence = getGeofence(location)

        val geofencingRequest = getGeofenceRequest(geofence)

        initGeofence(geofencingRequest)
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun initGeofence(geofencingRequest: GeofencingRequest) {
        geofencingClient.addGeofences(geofencingRequest, pendingBroadcastIntent)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                geoAlreadyInitialized = true
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
            }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun updateLocation() {
        locationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { location ->
            createNewGeofence(location)
        }
    }

    private fun getGeofenceRequest(geofence: Geofence) =
        GeofencingRequest.Builder()
            .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
            .addGeofence(geofence)
            .build()

    private fun getGeofence(location: Location) = Builder()
        .setCircularRegion(location.latitude, location.longitude, 200F)
        .setRequestId(geoId)
        .setTransitionTypes(GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER or GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
        .setExpirationDuration(NEVER_EXPIRE)
        .setNotificationResponsiveness(0)
        .build()

    private fun removeActualGeofence() {

        geofencingClient.removeGeofences(mutableListOf(geoId))
            .addOnFailureListener {}
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                if (geoAlreadyInitialized) count++
            }

    }

    private fun createObservers() {
        exitFromGeofence.observe(this) {
            updateLocation()
        }
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        // ...create notification channel
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that i was trying to use `locationClient.lastLocation` to get the user actual location, and when there was no last location to get it fail on create the geofence o the right place, just when i use the fake gps app the phone recorded a location and it works, so i changed to use [requestLocationUpdates](https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates) to get the actual locale.